# how to uninstall ubuntu 18.04 in dell n5110 and install windows

Tags: uninstall, grubrescue, efibootmgr

how to uninstall ubuntu 18.04 in dell n5110 and install windows back 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MV7BFccGzw/

Comment: Just install Windows.

Comment: To complete @Pilot6 comment, you just need to reinstall Windows because Windows **formate** the whole disc, Ubuntu (and other things) are removed in the process, so you restart with a white HDD (but his time of use isn't reset, it would be to easy **:P**)

Comment: I don't consider this an Ubuntu related problem. Installing Windows as the sole OS does not require you to have ANY OS on the system. You boot from a media and the rest follows by itself. If the media does not boot try to find out why not and there is 2 options: it is not a bootable media or you did not boot correctly (and yes booting depends on what is on the media). Nowhere does this need the OS currently installed.

Comment: Heck you can use gparted to delete all the partitions and then boot from the medium. It will show a "no OS found" notice (and halt) if it fails to boot from it.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vThTZtKGfw/

Answer (score 2):

Simply boot from the drive which contain Windows iso and then install it on the hdd where there is Ubuntu, note that this will delete all of your file on Ubuntu, after this operation on your hdd there will be only Windows

Comment: thanks for your response.. but i dont have dual os in my laptop. i have only ubuntu in my laptop. when i insert windows bootable usb it didnt load on my boot.

Comment: @karthick You need to boot from usb by entering in the boot menu, generally to enter it you need to press F12 or esc while your pc is starting, but your laptop can have different command, so try search on internet, once entered in boot menu select your usb

Comment: @karthick Probably you need to press Shift while starting pc until the menu appears

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vThTZtKGfw/